# Office 2011 - option + left / right keyboard shortcut not working

Tags: macos, keyboard, ms-office

When using Microsoft Office 2011 (Word, Powerpoint and Excel) on my Macbook Pro (running OS X 10.9.5) the `option + left arrow`, `option + shift + left arrow`, `option + right arrow` and `option + shift + right arrow` keyboard shortcuts don't work as they should e.g. skip (select) forward or back a word. This functionality works in non-Microsoft programs such as at the command line. All other keyboard shortcuts are working as they should.

I have checked under `Tools > Customise Keyboard` and they are assigned correctly. I have tried resetting shortcuts both within Office and in System Preferences without success. This has been going on a while - through successive Office updates. As a work-around I have reassigned this functionality to another shortcut but would like to know what the problem is.

Anyone experiencing similar or knows a solution?

Comment: option left? left what? left arrow?

Comment: @Buscar웃: `option + left arrow`

Answer (score 1):

I had my keyboard set to `Unicode Hex Input`. Setting this to `Australian` or `English` resolved the problem.